# windows batch file The system cannot find the batch label specified-exit

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm having a problem with a DOS batch file and labels. I keep getting this error:
there are two batch files(QQ.bat and Calling.bat) in the same folder.

the code of QQ.bat:

```
@echo off
set /a i=0
:loop
set /a i=i+1
echo %i%
c:
cd \Users
cd mytool
cd QQ
cd Bin
QQ.exe
if "%i%"=="2" goto exit 
goto loop
```

The code of Calling.bat:

```
@echo off
set/a i=0
:loop
set/a i=i+1
start /b cmd /c QQ.bat
if "%i%"=="4"  exit
goto loop
pause
```

the console's output "The system cannot find the batch label specified -exit",and excute severl QQ.exe by random and the amount is not correct ,while my excepted result is that there will be excute 8 QQ.exe simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

The console shows an error because **GOTO** statement is trying to jump to a label which doesn't exist.

From what I can understand by the use of goto exit in your script is that you want the script to exit at that point. For that use:

`GOTO:EOF` instead of `goto exit`.

Comment: Thank you very much .I followed your suggestion to fix my code .The error is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what your code is doing: `QQ.exe` is launched `8` times - but your code is reusing the `%i%` variable so you may not need it 8 times.

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,8) do start "" /d "c:\Users\mytool\QQ\Bin" "QQ.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have correctly defined labels, but incorrectly interpreted goto syntax.  Use "goto :exit" instead. You can find help on batch command by executing it with "/?" in command line (like "goto /?" )